# java program to print below number sequence

Tags: numbers

A method accepts number of elements as input and print like below. Suppose the `n` is `3`

```
1*2*3  
7*8*9  
4*5*6
```

if `n` is `5`

```
1*2*3*4*5
11*12*13*14*15
21*22*23*24*25
16*17*18*19*20
6*7*8*9*10
```

I don't know which pattern is this?

Comment: i think the output if n is 5 is: 1*2*3*4*5\n 11*12*13*14*15\n 21*22*23*24*25\n 6*7*8*9*10\n 16*17*18*19*20\n

Comment: share the  output when n is 7

Comment: If N=7, it would be like this:  1*2*3*4*5*6*7
15*16*17*18*19*20*21
29*30*31*32*33*34*35
43*44*45*46*47*48*49 
36*37*38*39*40*41*42
22*23*24*25*26*27*28
8*9*10*11*12*13*14